# failure in installing chardet

Tags: python, installation, chardet

I download a chardet module,placed it in `d:\\`and want it installed in python,
so I use the cmd :

> > `c:\\Python27\python.exe d:\\chardet\setup.py`

the win command says that:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\\chardet\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'`

but I am sure that the file '`README.rst`' is in dir `d:\\chardet`

I don't know how to deal with it ,and hoping for your help .

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
C:\Python27\python.exe D:\chardet\setup.py install
```